# BE Access DB Bloating when connected from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access application split FE/BE which imports data and exports reports to an Excel xlsm file. The users take various actions within the Excel report which add records to the BE DB. All connections to the BE DB are open and closed and the recordsets are closed before the db connection is closed and set to nothing. The BE is password protected and I have approximately 20 active users each day.

The backend database is bloating during use during the day and requires compacting each night. I am trying to isolate why the backend is growing. During the day it will grow from 10mb to over 100mb by the end of day.

The bloating is caused by the Excel links, if all actions are completed in Access the BE DB only grows by a few kb.

I have found many posts here and on Google and can't find any suggestions which keep the db to its normal size. I am aware that deleting and adding records causes bloating but we are only adding a few hundred records each day.

Sample Excel code: We are using five Excel reports. These reports are opened and the macros invoke approx 100 times per day.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rstJournal As DAO.Recordset

Set db = DAO.OpenDatabase(tmpDir & "DBname.accdb", False, False, "MS Access;PWD=Password")

Set rstJournal = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblJournal", Options:=dbAppendOnly)

rstJournal.AddNew
rstJournal!J_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1).Value

...

RstJournal.Update

If Not rstJournal Is Nothing Then rstJournal.Close
If Not db Is Nothing Then db.Close

Set rstJournal = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: You may wish to refer to my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868231/7531598).

Comment: One method is to use a temporary database (per user) created from scratch for the initial work, then transfer only the final data to the normal backend.

Comment: @Gustav - Thanks for the suggestion - I use temp tables for the data import already, the issue with bloating only occurs when the excel models start interacting with the  database.

Comment: @LeeMac - I am only seeing the bloating after exporting the reports to excel and Excel is then writing user results back to the database. I am already compacting the data automatically at night using vba as a scheduled task. I will add some code samples from excel

Comment: It's a temporary _database_, a separate (local) file. Tables in this will, of course, be temporary as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like every loop you open and close the Data Base and it could be a problem.

But you might want to use the code in such way.

```
Const dbFailOnError = 128
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = DAO.OpenDatabase(tmpDir & "DBname.accdb", False, False, "MS Access;PWD=Password")

For I = 0 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblJournal ( J_Name , field2 ) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT '" & ActiveCell.Offset(I, 1).value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(I, 2).value & "'"

    ' If next line throw an error then use it without dbFailOnError and disable this one
    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

    ' db.Execute strSQL

Next I

If Not db Is Nothing Then db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Sorry you did not provide the field names. So I used the field2 form

Asaf

Comment: @asaf I didn't include the full code, I only open the connection once then loop all lines and add the entries. I tried changing to SQL execute but the same issue, any other thoughts ? Thanks